# Vertically align element inside div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble aligning vertically my `h3` element in my `dim` div.

I've tried some methods but none of them seemed to work.

This is what I have:

[image]

I want that "NEW WAVE" h3 to be centered vertically inside that faded box, I managed to align it horizontally with `justify-content-center` but the `align-items-center` for vertically is not working.

Im using Bootstrap 4 btw.

here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="dim">
        <div class="new-wave d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <h3>NEW WAVE</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
.new-wave.d-flex.justify-content-center.align-items-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Wow! this one worked as well, thanks man!

Comment: If it was the appropriate answer for you then please UPVOTE my answer.

Comment: I's love to but I still don't have the reputation required to do so :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add this flex class to the parent container - .dim - ?

Comment: That was it! Thanks man!

Comment: No problem dude ! :)